# How to acces variable in outer class with same name as in the inner class

Tags: java, class, this, outer-join

This question is for Java

Here is an example:

```
     public class A {

        int thing = 1;

          public class B {

             int thing = 2;
             System.out.println("I want to print out thing from class A" +what goes here?);
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You qualify the variable with the class name and `this` :

```
System.out.println("I want to print out thing from class A" + A.this.thing);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `A.this.thing` for "what goes here?"

Answer (score 0):

you can access A's variable as `A.this.thing`